# Magento Error 404

Tags: php, aplicação-web, magento

Bom dia, estou com um problema quando ativo URL amigável no *Magento*.

Quando por exemplo acesso:

```
MINHAURL/customer/account/login/
```

recebo o seguinte erro

```
Not Found
The requested URL /customer/account/login/ was not found on this server.
```

O `.htaccess` está na Raiz, o `mod_rewrite` está ativo, e ainda continua com esse problema

alguém consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

eh muito provavel q o problema seja a biblioteca mod_rewrite.

ja aconteceu comigo, de habilitar a biblioteca na versao errada do PHP... pois eh comum vc ter a disposicao algumas versoes do PHP para trabalhar.. e acaba habilitando o mod_rewrite na versao errada.

para confirmar... crie um arquivo com phpinfo(), e verifique se a biblioteca esta mesmo habilitada.

tb eh importante reiniciar o servidor depois de ter habilitado a biblioteca.

sucesso ai.